# How to set current Xcode version In android studio?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

I just upgrade Flutter.

```
Flutter 1.15.17 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

After upgrading, When I try to run my current project in Android Studio then I didn't find/select my Simulator.

So I thought, I have to run `flutter doctor` to check where is fault.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.15.17, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Here what I got.

> ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.
>   Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.

Right now I'm using `Xcode 10.3`. Here How can I set my current Xcode version instead of Xcode 11.0 ?

Is it possible because I don't want to update MacOS as well as Xcode version.

Comment: You can't. You have to update the xcode to the latest version as well as. Or you should have not updated flutter. Rollback to the older version of flutter.